# Remove a term from an array during a for loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

I've been creating a system for storing objects that persist for a specified duration, then remove themselves. However, I'm having some trouble figuring out how to remove expired items from the array while the for loop is running (to minimize extra iterations through the array)

Here is what I've made so far. Terms in the list are flagged with a Boolean value indicating that they're done.

`For i = 0 To VisualEffects.Count - 1 Step 1
            VisualEffects(i).Update(gt)
            VisualEffects(i).Draw(sb, Pos, Cam)
            If VisualEffects(i).CD.isExpired() Then
                VisualEffects.RemoveAt(i)
                i = -1
            End If`

```
    Next
```

Why does this produce an error? How can I remove a term from an array and *continue iterating through the remainder of the loop?*

Regards

Ares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
i = -1
```

sets `i` to -1, causing the `For` loop to terminate.

If you can, reverse the order of the loop so that you start with the last array element and count down.  That makes the remove logic much more straightforward.

Comment: @user2891327, no, it should **not** be `i -= 1`.  You should do what both answers have told you to do and it's not that.

Answer (score 2):

.NET arrays are fixed-size so you can't actually remove an element from an array at all.  You can change the value of an element, so you can set an element to Nothing to remove the object that it referred to, but the element is still there.  If you read the MSDN documentation for the Array class, you'll see that the RemoveAt method throws a NotSupportedException for this reason.

If you're actually using a collection rather than an array then you can call RemoveAt but you need to loop from the last index to the first rather than first to last.  That way, removing an item will not affect the indexes of those items that you are yet to visit.

Comment: Given that there is apparently no compile error, sounds like a collection or list.